# Asterisk: check original Caller ID on transfer

Tags: asterisk, phone

I am using Asterisk 16.5.0 with usecallmanager patch (which allow me to use Cisco phones features). We have a number of ConfBridge rooms, which are supposed to be called by employees only. Some employees can call from their phones, some from mobiles and some from other sites. We do allow calls from phones and registered mobile phones and this is done through context separation. Any office phone is in "internal" context and any external call is in "external" context. If the CID belongs to registered mobile phone - context will be raised by AGI.

The problem starts on transferred calls - there is no straightforward way to check if it should be transferred or not, because Cisco phones are not filling any information in SIP headers which can determine transfer call from regular call. I know this after analyzing SIP packets, tcpdump output and tried any things around "pai" in Asterisk settings.

In other words - if A call to B and B press "Transfer" button - phone make totally new call to confbridge C and when channel is ready B press "Transfer" again and A goes straight to C.

At the moment of transfer Asterisk says:

```
Call 170e40426e1428e47b8b59022ab9e13b@172.20.1.9:5060 got a SIP call transfer from caller: (REFER)!
SIP transfer to extension 101@internal by 140@172.20.21.9
```

At this moment Asterisk knows transfer is happening but there is no way to catch it from dialplan, because channel is already connected via ConfBridge app.

Is there any way to set a trap on the way of transfer, like execute some dialplan code and check caller there?

The only way I know currently is to fill special variable with partner caller id on every call to/from every phone and check both this variable and number of SIP lines of this phone before entering ConfBridge.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco phone create a new call when you press transfer.

So no, there is no way get info before transfer compleated, except record each call and think last call sent to phone is transfered one.

AFTER transfer compleated phone send reinvite with new callerid in RPID, which can be used probably, but no mechanism in asterisk(require patching).

Other option is check AMI events and track all link/bridge events. But you have track rename events too.